# VB insert command issues?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

When i am trying to insert into my DB with a form, where the user chooses froma drop down list, and uses a date picker.

The error i am getting, is that the code says it cannot insert double, however i do not have double anywhere!

Any ideas???

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form3
    Dim Con As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim sqlstring As String
    Dim connstring As String
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim mon As Boolean
    Dim tues As Boolean
    Dim wed As Boolean
    Dim thur As Boolean
    Dim fri As Boolean
    Dim sat As Boolean
    Dim sun As Boolean
    Dim user As Integer
    Dim chosen As Date

    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        connstring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Assignment.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
        Con = New SqlConnection(connstring)
        Con.Open()
        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * from Users"
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, Con)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "Users")
        With cboname
            .DataSource = ds.Tables("Users")
            .DisplayMember = "Name"
            .ValueMember = "Id"
            .SelectedIndex = 0
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCommit.Click
        Dim Con As SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        Dim sqlstring As String
        Dim connstring As String
        Dim ds As DataSet
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
        connstring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Assignment.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
        Con = New SqlConnection(connstring)
        Con.Open()
        sqlstring = "Insert into Rota ('" + chosen + "','" + mon + "','" + tues + "','" + wed + "','" + thur + "','" + fri + "','" + sat + "','" + sun + "','" + user + "')"
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlstring, Con)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "Rota")
    End Sub
    Private Sub cbomon_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbomon.CheckedChanged
        mon = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub cbotues_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbotues.CheckedChanged
        tues = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub cbowed_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbowed.CheckedChanged
        wed = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub cbothurs_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbothurs.CheckedChanged
        thur = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub cbofri_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbofri.CheckedChanged
        fri = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub cbosat_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbosat.CheckedChanged
        sat = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub cbosun_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbosun.CheckedChanged
        sun = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub cboname_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboname.SelectedIndexChanged
        user = cboname.SelectedIndex
    End Sub

    Private Sub dtp1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtp1.ValueChanged
        chosen = dtp1.Value
        chosen.ToString()
        MsgBox(chosen)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is the error verbatim? Does it say it cannot covert a type to double? Does your table have a double datatype in any of the columns?

Comment: My table does not have a double data type. "Cannot Convert to Type Double"

Comment: You should use parameterized queries. Do not EVER try to concatenate a string to build a sql command.

Comment: Could you describe the datatype of the fields in the table `Rota`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `+` operator to concatenate strings, a DateTime, and several Booleans. It looks like the compiler allows this for `chosen`, but when it gets to `mon`, it decides to try to convert both sides to a Double to add them.

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c5t70w2.aspx) for the + operator, if one side of the operation is a string, and the other is a numeric value, the compiler will attempt to convert both to Double and add them. That's why you're seeing this problem.

As a first attempt, consider using the string concatenation operator `&` instead.

```
sqlstring = "Insert into Rota ('" & chosen & "','" & mon & "','" & tues & "','" & wed & "','" & thur & "','" & fri & "','" & sat & "','" & sun & "','" & user & "')"
```

Turning Option Strict On will help to catch those errors in the future.

As others have noted, you should never build a SQL string this way, but should use a parameterized query. If you're using OleDbCommand, it would look something like this (off the top of my head):

```
Using cmd = New OleDbCommand("Insert into Rota(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
    With cmd.Parameters
        .Add("@chosen", chosen)
        .Add("@mon", mon)
        .Add("@tues", tues)
        .Add("@wed", wed)
        .Add("@thur", thur)
        .Add("@fri", fri)
        .Add("@sat", sat)
        .Add("@sun", sun)
        .Add("@user", user)
    End With 

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Comment: And also parameterizing, for starters.

Comment: Thanks, that does help, but it thoews me a new error further down, now where it says "incorrect syntax near )", and this is the line  `da.Fill(ds, "Rota")`

Comment: Is it a compiler error or a runtime exception? I'm not familiar with Access, but if it were SQL Server, I'd question your INSERT statement, since I'm used to an INSERT in the form `INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2, ..., fieldn) VALUES (value1, value2, ..., valuen);` I've also never used DataAdapter.Fill on anything other than a SELECT statement.

Comment: @pmcoltrane The error is a run time error. So how would i push the data back to the DB if I'm not using a DataAdapter.Fill????

Comment: @user3343446 The `OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` call will will do that, but I think you'll need to open an `OleDbConnection` for it, not a `SqlConnection`. If you're still getting a runtime error after that, look at the syntax of your INSERT statement.

Comment: @pmcoltrane Thanks for help so far. I attach a pastebin link with code as it currently stands. I am now having the issue of `[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.`     http://pastebin.com/kX8YN2id